# vb.net - Removing the Bold effect from a label

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I have  labels on my form. I did the following to turn them to bold when the bold button is clicked:

```
Dim con4 As Control
For Each con4 In Me.Controls                
   con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
Next
```

And this works. Now I want to remove the bold if I click the same button again.
What i think about is an If statement like:

```
If con4.FontStyle <> "Bold" Then
   con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
End If
```

But this is not VB.Net. How can I write the above statement in VB.Net language?

Comment: My code is not complete as it is, but it provides the minimal for this question. Please don't ask me for it it won't help.

Comment: I don't know how to do it either, maybe I'll just use a variable. A `boolean` variable to be specific, that will determine if it's in `bold` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me.

You just need to use the condition `If Button.Font.Bold = True`

```
Dim con4 As Control
If Button1.Font.Bold = True Then
    For Each con4 In Me.Controls
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    Next
Else
    For Each con4 In Me.Controls
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    Next
End If
```

You could only include your labels controls in your for each and specify the condition on `Label.Font.Bold`.